# Angular2 - interpolated object is 'undefined' but console.log() works

Tags: angular

I'm working on a very simple Angular2 app, but I'm running into an issue where an interpolated component object is evaluated by the browser as `undefined`, though I am able to `console.log(this)` in the component and see the values, albeit with the 'Value below was evaluated just now' note.

For context, I've initiated my app with the Angular2 command line tool, but I am loosely following the Angular2 'Tour of Heroes' tutorial (which uses a zipped quickstart package to assemble the basic files)...

The template that is causing the issue is `person-detail.component.html`, where I very simply have:

```
<div>Welcome, {{ person.name }}</div>
```

Here is the associated `person-detail.component.ts`

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params }   from '@angular/router';
import { Location }                 from '@angular/common';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { PersonService } from './person.service';
import { Person } from './person';

@Component({
  selector: 'person-details',
  templateUrl: './person-details.component.html'
})

export class PersonDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() person: Person;
   constructor(
    private personService: PersonService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ) {};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this.personService.getPerson(+params['id']))
      .subscribe(person => this.person = person);

      console.log(this) //THIS LOGS THE COMPLETE OBJECT AS I WANT IT, BUT WITH THE 'Value below...' NOTE
  };
}
```

and `person.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Person } from './person';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class PersonService {
    private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/api/';

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        console.log('Service ready...');
    }

  getPeople(): Promise<Person[]> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http
      .get(this.apiUrl + 'people', options)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().data as Person[])
  }

  getPerson(id: number): Promise<Person> {
    return this.getPeople()
      .then(people => people.find(person => person.id === id));
  }  
}
```

But when I navigate to the page, I get the error `inline template:0:5 caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`, though the data returned by `console.log()` looks good.

Conceptually, I understand what's happening... the section of the page is rendering before the  object is fully-formed. But I'm confused, because as far as I can tell, I put things together in exactly the same way as the 'Tour of Heroes' tutorial, which worked just fine - except for the fact that I initiated my project with the command line tools (which builds the project slightly differently) and I'm connecting to my own API with some header options, etc...

How can I set it so that the section of the page will wait until the object is fully-formed before trying to render it?

Note - if I try to interpolate `{{ person }}`, the browser displays  `[object Object]`

Comment: and `console.log(person)` instead of `console.log(this)` what it gives you ?

Comment: `console.log(person)` is an error, but `console.log(this.person)` logs `undefined`

Comment: but `console.log(this)` is a complete object, with a `person` attribute

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `console.log` is giving you the wrong impression because `person` is still `undefined` by the time you try to access it in the template, although you don't have time to appreciate the change in the console if the response from the server is fast enough. So you need to use the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator).

```
<div>Welcome, {{ person?.name }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you might want to consider using [typescript getters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html). They will allow you to have a default value for your property.

```
export class PersonDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() personInput: Person;
  get person(){
    return personInput || {};
  }
```

Call it like:

```
<person-details [personInput]="details"></person-details>
```

And then in your PersonDetailsComponent, you can use it without any change:

```
<div>Welcome, {{ person.name }}</div>
```